# Once a file extension is added to .gitignore how do I remove its files from the untracked files list?

Tags: git

Visual Studio has a new intellisence database file and when I ran `git status` I found it

> On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   Untracked files:
>     (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>           ServerSideCode.VC.db

Like its predecessor, `*.sdf`, this [can be added to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408065/575530). I edited my .gitignore to include `*.VC.db`. Now when I run `git status` I see:

> On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   Untracked files:
>     (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>           ServerSideCode.VC.db

What additional step, beyond adding a file to the .gitignore file, do I need in order ro to remove the file from the list of untracked files returned by `git status`?

(N.B. I realise that I could run `git status -uno` but I want to know the additional step required to ignore new file types recently added to my .gitignore file.)

Comment: You can try doing `git check-ignore -v ServerSideCode.VC.db`. If there is a gitignore rule properly configured, that should return which .gitignore file that contains a matching ignore rule. If that command returns nothing, then there is no ignore rule which matches the specified file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the extension to .gitignore it should no longer show up in `git status`. Are you sure there's no typo in your .gitignore, and that the file is placed correctly?

Comment: Ah, I think I may have edited the wrong .gitignore. I edited the one in ~ but I think it may  be the one in ~/Source/Repos/ServerSideCode I should have edited. I'll check, thanks.